# How can SystemInfo.deviceUniqueIdentifier be unique?

Tags: unity-game-engine

According to http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SystemInfo-deviceUniqueIdentifier.html, `SystemInfo.deviceUniqueIdentifier`

> It is guaranteed to be unique for every device (Read Only).

If you delete and reinstall your application, this value will change. **How can it guarantee that there isn't another iPhone in the world that happened to generate the same identifier?**

(I know that the identifier is pretty long so it is quite unlikely for this to happen - but I'd like to know why)

Answer (score 1):

As the description says, it's typically some form of device ID, set by the vendor:

> iOS: on pre-iOS7 devices it will return hash of MAC address. On iOS7
> devices it will be UIDevice identifierForVendor or, if that fails for
> any reason, ASIdentifierManager advertisingIdentifier.
>
> Windows Store
> Apps: uses AdvertisingManager::AdvertisingId for returning unique
> device identifier, if option in 'PC Settings -> Privacy -> Let apps
> use my advertising ID for experiences across apps (turning this off
> will reset your ID)' is disabled, Unity will fallback to
> HardwareIdentification::GetPackageSpecificToken().Id.

Even if these values were random, they come out in the same format as a [GUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier) with 32 hexadecimal characters (128bits). The number of possibilities is rather large.

From Wikipedia:

> The total number of unique such GUIDs is 2^122 (approximately 5.3×10^36). This number is so large that the probability of the same number being
> generated randomly twice is negligible; however other GUID versions
> have different uniqueness properties and probabilities, ranging from
> guaranteed uniqueness to likely duplicates. Assuming uniform
> probability for simplicity, the probability of one duplicate would be
> about 50% if every person on earth as of 2014 owned 600 million GUIDs.